# Random malloc errors

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, malloc

I have a project that involves adjusting the playback speed (aka pitch) of an MP3 according to the value of sensor.  I have tested it with both a trimpot and a hall effect sensor (calculating the RPMs).

In both cases, the code crashes with an malloc error at seemingly random points.

The code is running on a Pi 2B and runs from the CLI.  Total memory load when it is running (across the whole system) is only around 40mb.

The two scripts can be found here:
https://github.com/mpember/speedoplayer

Any tips on where to start troubleshooting the error?

When I get a malloc error from the same code, it shows no traceback.

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python3': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x7430d320 ***
```

Comment: Can you provide backtrace and error message?

Comment: added traceback above

Comment: Code should be included *in the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Very similar error has been raised in the [Github repository](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15/issues/4).

Did you try to connect Pin 1 (ADDR) of the ADS1115 to either GND or VDD?

Comment: It would appear that during transport, some of the dupont connectors became tempramental.  After checking every connection, the I/O error is no longer occurring.  However, the malloc errors remain.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to build a clean install on another system.  However, I switched from using Gstreamer to Mplayer for the media playback, and the problem appears to have been resolved.